# Dummit and Foote proof of Theorem 3 (p.512, third edition).

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUlqs.png)

I am not sure I understand this proof correctly. In the text highlighted in yellow, is it correct that we are fixing an arbitrary $x \in F$ (or $F[x]$)? If so, the proof seems to suggest that $\pi(x)$ is a root for $p$ in $K$ for any $x \in F$, it feels like I am missing something here, can someone please clarify the proof?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @AnotherUser Ill keep that in mind for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ is not an arbitrary element of either $F$ or $F[x]$. It is the indeterminate for the polynomial ring $F[x]$. Denoting its image under the projection map $\pi$ by $\overline{x}$, we see that when we plug $\overline{x}$ into $p(x)$ we get $0$, hence this *specific* element of the quotient $K = F[x]/(p(x))$ is root of $p(x)$.